# Hyperlinks in Bing Maps infobox breaks Windows 8 App Navigation State

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps, winjs, infobox

I have Bing Maps on a page in my WinJS Windows 8 Application.

The Map has a few pins each with its own Infobox. When clicking on the pin it displays the infobox correctly with its content. The content contains a hyperlink that links to a different page in the Windows 8 Application. The app navigates to this page correctly, however the back button stops working and the App Bar can't be accessed either. (Navigating to the page normally works fine)

I think something goes wrong with how the page navigates and how the navigator records the state. I am new to this so it might also just be a stupid question.

Here is the code in the page's .js file:

```
    // For an introduction to the Page Control template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232511
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/testBing/testBing.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            // TODO: Initialize the page here.
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Map', { callback: initMap });
        }
    });


})();

var pinInfobox = null;

function initMap() {
    try {
        var mapOptions =
        {
            credentials: "credentials",
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-33.961176, 22.420985),
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
            zoom: 5
        };
        var mapDiv = document.querySelector("#mapdiv");
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
        centerPosition();
    }
    catch (e) {
        var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(e.message);
        md.showAsync();
    }
}

function addPushPin(location) {
    map.entities.clear();
    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, null);

    pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { title: 'My Pushpin', visible: true, description: "<a href='/pages/player/player.html'>Profile</a>" });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', displayInfobox);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', hideInfobox);

    map.entities.push(pushpin);
    map.entities.push(pinInfobox);
}


function hideInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
}

function centerPosition() {
    var geolocator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
    geolocator.getGeopositionAsync().then(function (loc) {
        var mapCenter = map.getCenter();
        mapCenter.latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
        mapCenter.longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
        map.setView({ center: mapCenter, zoom: 15 });
        addPushPin(mapCenter);


    });
}

function displayInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({ title: e.target.Title, innerHTML: e.target.Description, visible: true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 25) });
    pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
}
```

The HTML just has the following

```
    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!--Bing Mapps Reference -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appx:///Bing.Maps.JavaScript//js/veapicore.js"></script>

    <link href="testBing.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="testBing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="testBing fragment">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Welcome to testBing</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <div id="mapdiv"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a full, actual browser navigation? E.ge all your code gets unloaded? If your doing this with the debugger loaded, you'll see the JavaScript console output items that indication a navigation.

Comment: Its not in a browser. Its a Windows 8 store application that will eventually also be used on a Windows Phone. (Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question)

Comment: I've managed to attach a method to the click event of the infobox.
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pinInfobox, 'click', testMethod);
 Using WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/player/player.html') then allows me to navigate to the other page and that does not break the navigation.

However I would like to add multiple links on the infobox, so this solution won't work for that scenario.

Comment: WWAs have the same API surface as browsers. If you have <a href="foo.html">Foo</a>, then when you click it *by default* it will move the whole page to /foo.html in your package and tear down your script.

Why don't you just listen to the click event on the parent div, and handle the bubbled event, and call e.preventDefault() on the event so the default navigation (that I just discussed) doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dominic, however we've now been told to use C# and xaml instead. I would still like to try this out, but I will have to do that when I find time.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Dominic Hopton is correct: foo.html gets loaded as the whole page instead of as part of your app's navigation process.  If the links are supposed to do an app navigation (as opposed to open in an external web browser), you can add this code to your page's ready function to convert the link click into a navigation event.

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nav.navigate(e.target.href);
});
```

If you have some links that should navigate and some that should open in a browser, you can modify the query.  For example, if can can add a CSS class to links that should open in a web browser, you could change the query to:

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("a:not(.defaultClick)")
```

You might also be able to modify the query to examine the href attribute of the link to check for "http" like so:

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("a:not([href^=http])")
```

I have not tested this last example yet, but if it works as I suspect it would, it would have a links that start with "http" (so including "https") behave normally, while all links that have a relative URL or a package URL will be converted to navigation events.

I don't recommend that you do this blindly, but depending on your app, this simple shortcut might change the behavior to match your expectations.